# JFileChooser does not show files with filter applied

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

so i've got this really basic piece of code initializing a JFileChooser with a File Name Filter. Currently you should see only .txt Files, later I want to use a custom filename.

```
JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
     dialog.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt",".txt"));
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.showOpenDialog(dialog);
```

The thing is, when the filter is applied, there aren't any files shown, not even .txt files as they would be supposed to. I've tried this with several file endings, i've also tried using "*.txt" but nothing works. 
This really bothers me because i just don't get why something that basic wouldn't work..

Comment: oh and yeah, there definitly are some .txt files at the location i'm looking at

Answer (score 6):

From the [FileNameExtensionFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) class document:

> An implementation of FileFilter that filters using a specified set of
>   extensions. The extension for a file is the portion of the file name
>   **after** the last ".". Files whose name does not contain a "." have no
>   file name extension. File name extension comparisons are case
>   insensitive.

You just need to remove the full stops from the extension filters as this is already included when filtering, the description is fine

So this line:

```
dialog.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt",".txt"));
```

should be:

```
dialog.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt","txt"));
```

Comment: oh man, really could've tried that. but for some reason I always only saw it with the dot. well anyway, thanks man :)